# Trouble with css floating

Tags: css, animation, hyperlink, transition, floating

I have a little problem with floating.

I need to display my links side by side with 20px margin, but it does not work.

### CSS

```
ul li{
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 20px;
}
.link {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size:18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 0;
    position: absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.link a{


    text-decoration:none;
    color:gray;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease;

}
.link span {
    position: inherit;
    left:-100%;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    background: #fb6f5e;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;
}
.link a:hover{
    color:#fb6f5e;

}
.link:hover span {
overflow:hidden;
position: inherit;
    bottom: 1px;
    left:100%;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    background: #fb6f5ee;
   -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;

}
```

### HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><div class="link">Start</a><span></span></div></li>
<li><a href="#"><div class="link">About</a><span></span></div></li>
<li><a href="#"><div class="link">Other</a><span></span></div></li>
<li><a href="#"><div class="link">Contact</a><span></span></div></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SD58Z/727/

Comment: To begin with, your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a ton of syntax issues

1. extra `</div>` tags
2. Improper tag order: `<a><div></a></div>` should be `<a><div></div></a>`
3. Incorrect Hex code for background color on `<span>` in CSS

You are trying to float items and also absolute position them.  Pick one or the other.

Using this CSS (i deleted 2 lines of code) it works fine.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/SD58Z/725/

```
ul li{
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0 20px;
}
.link {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size:18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.link a{


    text-decoration:none;
    color:gray;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease;

}
.link span {
    position: inherit;
    left:-100%;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    background: #fb6f5e;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;
}
.link a:hover{
    color:#fb6f5e;

}
.link:hover span {
overflow:hidden;
position: inherit;
    bottom: 1px;
    left:100%;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    background: #fb6f5ee;
   -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;

}
```

With your HTML fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/SD58Z/732/

Comment: It works fine look at my Fiddle.  You need to delete all of your position: lines.

Comment: Again... Invalid markup with this example.  You are now missing an ending div tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SD58Z/768/

Position: inheret in the spans means they are position absolute of whatever they are contained within...  Set their container to relative and the spans to absolute, and wallaa, it works.  No need to go so far up the tree.  See fiddle linked above.

Comment: Thank you so much. I struggled with this. I need to learn everything about css/html.

Comment: You have to be careful with position: absolute because as you have found out, it can destroy stuff =)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SD58Z/738/)

Your link was set to position absolute so it was outside the flow of elements. Meaning all elements ended on top of each other.

You were also having some unclosed div tags and other html errors.

I moved some things around in the html to make it work. I do think this can be optimized. The reason why the underline hover effect did not work was because of my changes in the html structure (which I think is what you intended in the first place).

**css**

```
ul{
    padding-left:0px;
}

ul li{
    float:left;
    display: block;
    margin-left:20px;
    position:relative;
    color:inherit;
}

ul li:first-child{
    margin-left:0px;
}
.link {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size:18px;
     overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.link a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:gray;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease;
    position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.link a:hover{
    color:#fb6f5e;

}

.link span {
    position: absolute;
    left:-100%;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    background: #fb6f5e;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;
}

.link:hover span {
    bottom: 1px;
    left:0%;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    background: #fb6f5ee;
   -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;

}
```

**Html:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="link">

            <a href="#">Start
                 <span></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="link">

            <a href="#">About
                 <span></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="link">

            <a href="#">Other
                 <span></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="link">

            <a href="#">Contact
                 <span></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: great, but my line animation disappeared.

Comment: Use text-decoration: underline; on a:hover to get that back

Comment: Yes, but animation don't work with text-decoration, so for this reason I did it differently

Comment: I see that now.  You need to modify how your selectors work once you fix your HTML.  He fixed your HTML for you partially, which made it not work correctly.

Comment: Updated my answer, updating explaination in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I just played with your code for a minute and fixed the HTML. There seems to be some useless CSS but this gets you going.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><div class="link"><a href="#">Start</a><span></span></div></li>
    <li><div class="link"><a href="#">About</a><span></span></div></li>
    <li><div class="link"><a href="#">Other</a><span></span></div></li>
    <li><div class="link"><a href="#">Contact</a><span></span></div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
ul li{
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0 20px;
}
.link {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size:18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.link a{


    text-decoration:none;
    color:gray;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease;

}
.link span {
    position: inherit;
    left:-100%;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    background: #fb6f5e;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;
}
.link a:hover{
    color:#fb6f5e;

}
.link:hover span {
overflow:hidden;
position: inherit;
    bottom: 1px;
    left:100%;
    height: 1px;
    width:100%;
    background: #fb6f5ee;
   -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;

}
```

Comment: This is still invalid HTML mark up.  You can not start an A tag then start a div tag and then end the A tag without first ending the div tag.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid again, thats the only reason what you are doing is working in the first place, you are targeting markup that is wrong.  In the example above you are again, missing your </div> tag.......

Comment: Lukas, Michael is correct. You are putting the tags in the wrong order. Put the div first, then the a and close the a then the span then close the span then close the div.

Comment: Right, I corrected it, but I don't know how to group a line class to get back my animation hover

Comment: So now you're not using the UL? That way will work too. Just add a margin: 0 10px to .menu